# How to make python tkinter root close itself only?

Tags: python, tkinter

I have a number of roots (frames) in my program. How do I set the command for the OS's exit button (the x at the top of the panel)? I want to make it so that I can close just one pane, not the entire program. I found code for making your own exit button on the frame itself, but I don't want to have to reset the position of all the buttons I already have.

edit: I forgot to mention I'm using Ubuntu

edit2:

```
root3 = Tk()
root = Tk()
root2 = Tk()
```

This is how I'm initializig the objects for three frames (I don't have enough reputation to post images). I looked at Toplevel and I think **Bryan Oakley** means I should do something like this:

```
frame1 = Toplevel()
frame2 = Toplevel()
frame3 = Toplevel()
```

However, doing so makes a fourth (empty) frame appear, while the three I need are still intact with all the widgets I need present.

Could you explain the difference between using Tk() and Toplevel() and how each is meant to be used?

I attempted to use **Fredrik's** solution but I received the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "GUI_Robot_Control.py", line 823, in <module>
    root.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", root.destroy())
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk/Tkinter.py", line 1630, in wm_protocol
    'wm', 'protocol', self._w, name, command)
_tkinter.TclError: can't invoke "wm" command:  application has been destroyed
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Roots and frames are two very different things in Tkinter.  Thus, it is kinda hard to help you without any code.  Could you please post your script?

Comment: If you have multiple root windows (instances of `Tk`), you're doing something very wrong. Is that what you're doing, or when you say "number of roots" are you talking about instances of `Toplevel`?

Answer (score 1):

Not clear if you mean multiple `Tk` instances or multiple `Toplevel` windows, but if you need to control what happens when a user clicks the close button on either of them, you can use register a protocol handler:

```
widget.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", handler)
```

After this call, the close button will call the function `handler` instead of closing the window.  The default behaviour is similar to:

```
widget.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", widget.destroy)
```

(yes, this is a bit obscure, but any Tkinter book should explain this)

Answer (score 1):

In an edit to the original question you ask about the difference between `Tk` and `Toplevel`.

`Tk()` creates a root window. Your app must always have exactly one of these. All tkinter apps must have a root window, that's just how it's designed to work. When this window is destroyed, your app will exit (typically, though it's technically possible for that not to be true).

`Toplevel(...)` creates new, "top level" windows. That is, windows that are not directly connected to the root window. These float on the desktop and can have a title bar, close buttons, etc. They look and behave almost exactly like the root window, except that you can destroy instances of `Toplevel` without destroying your entire application.

If you are creating an app with three windows, you have two choices. First, you can use the root window and two instances of `Toplevel`. The second option is to create a root window and *three* instances of `Toplevel`, then hide the original root window.

In every case, you can use the `protocol` method to catch when the window is destroyed by the user clicking on a button in the titlebar. You can then either veto the destruction of the window, or do some other things such as closing a database connection, opening a dialog to ask the user to save unsaved data, etc.

Comment: Thanks! I was able to fix the issue by having one root window and two instances of 'Toplevel' as you suggested!

Answer (score 0):

May I direct you to this question which probably has your answer in it:

[How do I handle the window close event in Tkinter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/111155/how-do-i-handle-the-window-close-event-user-clicking-the-x-button-in-a-pytho)

Comment: I tried that but I got the error in the edit above. Thanks though! If you have any other suggestions I'd greatly appreciate them!