# Unclosable window using tkinter

Tags: python, user-interface, python-3.x, tkinter, window

Hey I am making a program that take a picture using my webcam when I type the wrong password. The program will be open and I want it unclosable.
I need to know how to make a window unclosable using tkinter.

Comment: If you want it un _cos_ able, it has to be a  _sin_ ed application.

Comment: @TigerhawkT3: Stick to the question, don't go off on a tangent. :P

Comment: Anyway, what do you mean by "uncloseable" (assuming you even mean "uncloseable")? Do you just mean you want no close box (the X in the top-right corner on Windows the red dot in the top-left corner on Mac, etc.)? Or more than that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try all of the many things @abarnert suggested, but I think the easiest way would be to just ignore the close event.

From [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/111155/how-do-i-handle-the-window-close-event-in-tkinter):

> Here you have a concrete example:

```
import Tkinter as tk
import tkMessageBox as messagebox
root = tk.Tk()

def on_closing():
    if messagebox.askokcancel("Quit", "Do you want to quit?"):
        root.destroy()

root.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", on_closing)
root.mainloop()
```

(edited code for Windows)

So change `on_closing()` to 

`def on_closing():
    pass`
and that makes it unclosable. I tried <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F4</kbd>, the close button, closing it from the Windows Taskbar, all to no avail. The only way I was able to kill it was to use Task Manager.

Answer (score 0):

Tkinter doesn't have any way to do this directly. But it does have something that *may* be good enough, or it may be too much overkill: the [`overrideredirect`](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/wm.htm#Tkinter.Wm.overrideredirect-method) flag:

> If non-zero, this prevents the window manager from decorating the window. In other words, the window will not have a title or a border, and it cannot be moved or closed via ordinary means.

That's not quite up-to-date; it may actually have a title or border on some platforms… but it won't be closable.

This is easy to use: just do `root.overrideredirect(True)` (or, if you want to do it to a different `Toplevel` window instead of your root, `window.overrideredirect(True)`).

---

But notice that it can't be *moved or closed*, not just that it can't be closed. (It also can't be resized, if you want that.)

So, the only thing you can do is set the flag, but then bind the mouse-button events to handle moving manually. For example, in your window's `__init__` method:

```
self.overrideredirect(True) # if this is a Toplevel
#self.parent.overrideredirect(True) # if this is a Frame on root

self.bind('<ButtonPress-1>', self.move_start)
self.bind('<ButtonRelease-1>', self.move_end)
self.bind('<B1-Motion>', self.move_move)
```

And then:

```
def move_start(self, event):
    self.startx, self.starty = event.x, event.y

def move_stop(self, event):
    self.move_move(event)

def move_move(self, event):
    x = self.winfo_x() + event.x - self.startx
    y = self.winfo_y() + event.y - self.starty
    self.geometry("+%s+%s" % (x, y))
```

---

Obviously, if you want any widgets within the window to accept clicks, you probably don't want to make the whole window a drag area. In fact, you may not want to make the whole window a drag area even if it doesn't have anything to click, because that's not really following Mac or Windows human interface guidelines. You could fake a grip area—a title bar, a border around the window, etc.—just by, e.g., adding a `Label` pinned to the side(s) you want to grip from and only `bind`ing there, or by creating a "child" window inset from the main window that steals the `bind`ings. But this is never going to look like a "native" window.

If you really need a native window, but with the close box (the `X` in the top-right corner on Windows, the red dot in the top-left on Mac, etc.) disabled or missing (and, on Windows, with the "close" item on the window menu disabled, and Alt+F4, and so on, and similarly for X11…)… As far as I know, there's no cross-platform way to do that in Tkinter. You will have to write code for each platform that gets at the underlying native window objects and does native window things to them. At that point, you probably want to look at using a more powerful windowing library than Tkinter—e.g., I believe Qt, Gtk+, and wx all have much simpler ways of creating a normal window but with the close box disabled.