# How to bind Alt-F4 with Python tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter

I am building a GUI application using Python and Tkinter.
I want to control the behavior of the program when the user closes it.

I've installed a new `WM_DELETE_WINDOW` protocol using:

```
root = Tk()
root.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", lambda: closes_gracefully())
```

This indeed is working when the user clicks the `X` button on the titlebar, but it is NOT working when the user presses <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>F4</kbd>.

I tried binding the key sequence: `root.bind("<Alt-F4>", lambda: closes_gracefully())` but it did not work.

How can I capture the <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>F4</kbd> event?

Comment: `lambda: closes_gracefully()` is just `closes_gracefully`, by the way.

Comment: Just tried in my app and this works well for me: `self.bind('<Alt-Key-F4>', self.whatever_your_want)`

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30157521/unclosable-window-using-tkinter

Comment: @CommonSense: thanks - my issue was with the binding statement - should be `<Alt-Key-F4>`

Comment: Your current code works fine for me. Please add a [mcve].

Comment: Just a note: Alt+F4 is platform dependent, for example Macs use Cmd+Q / Cmd+W.

Comment: @Melebius, they arent the same, try them in chrome, they close the entire application/active tab respectively, rather than the active window as Alt-F4 does

Comment: @NickA Yes, that’s their correct behavior. I just wanted to point out that they are used _instead_ of Alt+F4 on Macs. (There is also Shift+Cmd+W shortcut used to close a window containing tabs as you mentioned.) Therefore I would prefer a platform independent solution instead of hardcoded binding of Alt+F4.

Answer (score 3):

For this purpose, you could use `atexit.register`.

It works like a stack that is executed when the program gets closed. Every time you do `register(function)`, this function gets pushed on top. If you added a, b and c they get executed in the opposite order(c, b, a).

In your case, you should do:

```
register(closes_gracefully)
```

You should note that this works almost always, except with crashes(alt-f4 works too, just tested it).

You can even use `register` as a decorator when the function takes no parameters:

```
@register
def bye():
    print("I'm out!")
```