# Prevent multiple toplevels from opening?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I have a object oriented tkinter program set up.
I have initialized a variable to store `Toplevel()` in as

```
self.toplevel = None
```

Then when I create the actual `Toplevel` window I simply assign it to the variable:

```
self.toplevel = Toplevel()
```

The thing is...when the `Toplevel()` window is closed, the value still remains in the variable `self.toplevel`. How can I reset the variable back to None after closing the window so that I can perform a check:

```
if (self.toplevel == None):
    self.toplevel = Toplevel()
```

Or are there any other methods to prevent multiple `Toplevel` Windows from opening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check this [How do I handle the window close event in Tkinter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/111155/how-do-i-handle-the-window-close-event-in-tkinter)

Assign the value `None` to `self.toplevel` after the `Toplevel`closes usign a callback function `TopCloses`. For this, write a method within the GUI class to access the `toplevel` attribute and set it's value to `None` inside the callback function.

In your main program,

```
def TopCloses():
    top.destroy()
    #Call the setTopLevel method and assign the attribute toplevel value None
    guiObject.setTopLevel(None)

top.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", TopCloses)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: This would prevent ALL Toplevels(), right? But I need to filter out so that I can have various unique Toplevels() open at the same time but not the same ones.

Comment: Yes! I had to modify the idea a bit.
I simply added function in class:
        def toplevel_close(self):
            self.toplevel_incredients.destroy()
            self.toplevel_incredients = None

Then the protocol to the self.toplevel when it is created:
     self.toplevel.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", self.toplevel_close)

Answer (score 1):

Here is my solution:

```
#somewhere in __init__ make
self.window = None
#I took this piece of code from my bigger app and I have a function 
#self.makevariables(), which is called in init, which contains the line above.
def instructions(self):      
    if self.window == None: #here I check whether it exists, if not make it, else give focus to ok button which can close it
        self.window = Toplevel(takefocus = True)
        #some optional options lol
        self.window.geometry("200x200")
        self.window.resizable(0, 0)
        #widgets in the toplevel
        Label(self.window, text = "NOPE").pack() 
        self.window.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", self.windowclosed) #this overrides the default behavior when you press the X in windows and calls a function
        self.okbutton = Button(self.window, text = "Ok", command = self.windowclosed, padx = 25, pady = 5)
        self.okbutton.pack()
        self.okbutton.focus()
        self.okbutton.bind("<Return>", lambda event = None:self.windowclosed())
    else:
        self.okbutton.focus()  #You dont need to give focus to a widget in the TopLevel, you can give the focus to the TopLevel, depending how you want it
       #self.window.focus() works too    
def windowclosed(self): #function to call when TopLevel is removed
    self.window.destroy()
    self.window = None
```

Answer (score 0):

These are all overly complicated solutions imo.

I just use win32gui as such:

```
toplevel_hwid = win32gui.FindWindow(None, '<Top Level Window Title>')

if toplevel_hwid:
    print(f'Top level window already open with HWID: {toplevel_hwid}')
    win32gui.SetForegroundWindow(toplevel_hwid)
    return
else:
    <create new top level>
```

Simple, easy, and gives you the flexibility to close, move, focus, etc.