# How to force user to select at least one check button

Tags: python, python-3.x, checkbox, tkinter, tk-toolkit

I have a program I am working on and want the user to select their interests, and when they are done press submit. How would I only allow the user to press submit if at least one button is checked.

```
from tkinter import *

check = Tk()
check.title("Interests")
CheckVar1 = IntVar()
CheckVar2 = IntVar()
CheckVar3 = IntVar()
CheckVar4 = IntVar()
CheckVar5 = IntVar()


C1 = Checkbutton(check, text = "Horror", variable = CheckVar1, \
                 onvalue = 1, offvalue = 0, height=1, \
                 width = 20)
C2 = Checkbutton(check, text = "Action", variable = CheckVar2, \
                 onvalue = 1, offvalue = 0, height=1, \
                 width = 20)
C3 = Checkbutton(check, text = "Documentary", variable = CheckVar3, \
                 onvalue = 1, offvalue = 0, height=1, \
                 width = 20)
C4 = Checkbutton(check, text = "Science fiction", variable = CheckVar4, \
                 onvalue = 1, offvalue = 0, height=1, \
                 width = 20)
C5 = Checkbutton(check, text = "Comedy", variable = CheckVar5, \
                 onvalue = 1, offvalue = 0, height=1, \
                 width = 20)

submit_btn = Button(check, text = "Submit", command = lambda: check.destroy())     


C1.pack()
C2.pack()
C3.pack()
C4.pack()
C5.pack()
submit_btn.pack()
check.mainloop()

if CheckVar1.get():
    #dosomething
if CheckVar2.get():
    #dosomething
if CheckVar3.get():
    #dosomething
if CheckVar4.get():
    #dosomething
if CheckVar5.get():
    #dosomething
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add a handler function that checks whether at least one box is checked, before destroying the window.

You can do so easily with the following logic:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import messagebox

check = Tk()
check.title("Interests")

CheckVar1 = BooleanVar()
CheckVar2 = BooleanVar()
CheckVar3 = BooleanVar()
CheckVar4 = BooleanVar()
CheckVar5 = BooleanVar()


C1 = Checkbutton(check, text = "Horror", variable = CheckVar1, \
                 onvalue = 1, offvalue = 0, height=1, \
                 width = 20)
C2 = Checkbutton(check, text = "Action", variable = CheckVar2, \
                 onvalue = 1, offvalue = 0, height=1, \
                 width = 20)
C3 = Checkbutton(check, text = "Documentary", variable = CheckVar3, \
                 onvalue = 1, offvalue = 0, height=1, \
                 width = 20)
C4 = Checkbutton(check, text = "Science fiction", variable = CheckVar4, \
                 onvalue = 1, offvalue = 0, height=1, \
                 width = 20)
C5 = Checkbutton(check, text = "Comedy", variable = CheckVar5, \
                 onvalue = 1, offvalue = 0, height=1, \
                 width = 20)


def submitHandle():
    anyChecked = CheckVar1.get() | CheckVar2.get() | CheckVar3.get(
    ) | CheckVar4.get() | CheckVar5.get()
    if anyChecked:
        check.destroy()
    else:
        messagebox.showerror("Error", "Please check at least one.")


submit_btn = Button(check, text="Submit", command=lambda: submitHandle())

C1.pack()
C2.pack()
C3.pack()
C4.pack()
C5.pack()
submit_btn.pack()
check.mainloop()
```

P.S. Note that you should use `BooleanVar` and not `IntVar` for on-off checkboxes. Also, consider [adding a check](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/111155/how-do-i-handle-the-window-close-event-in-tkinter) on window close.

Answer (score 0):

To make this easier to handle, you could create a list of interests, then use them to loop everything. This will also make it easier to add stuff in the future, for example:

```
from tkinter import *

check = Tk()
check.title("Interests")

def destroy():
    if 1 in [vars[interest].get() for interest in interests]:
        check.destroy()

interests = ["Horror", "Action", "Documentary", "Science fiction", "Comedy"]

vars = {interest:IntVar() for interest in interests}
boxes = [Checkbutton(check, text = interest, variable = vars[interest], \
                 onvalue = 1, offvalue = 0, height=1, \
                 width = 20) for interest in interests]

submit_btn = Button(check, text = "Submit", command = destroy)


tmp = [box.pack() for box in boxes]
submit_btn.pack()
```