# How to recreate a stable environment (IPython)

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, anaconda, ipython, spyder

Due to a bug in IPython 7.13.0 i can not use matplotlib, as described in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60897047/spyder-plots-non-responding) question:

```
An error ocurred while starting the kernel
RROR:tornado.application:Exception in callback functools.partial(.advance_eventloop at 0x000001A802791318>)
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "path\anaconda3\lib\site‑packages\tornado\ioloop.py", line 743, in _run_callback
ret = callback()
File "path\anaconda3\lib\site‑packages\ipykernel\kernelbase.py", line 310, in advance_eventloop
eventloop(self)
File "path\anaconda3\lib\site‑packages\ipykernel\eventloops.py", line 232, in loop_tk
app.tk.createfilehandler(stream.getsockopt(zmq.FD), READABLE, notifier)
AttributeError: '_tkinter.tkapp' object has no attribute 'createfilehandler'
```

I use Anaconda, Python 3.7.6 and Spyder 4.1.2 (and Windows 10). How can i switch to a stable version? I have tried:

```
conda update ipykernel
conda update conda
conda update anaconda
conda update spyder
```

Any idea which version is under my environment stable?

Comment: This is not the place to report bugs. Please report it in the `ipykernel` [issue tracker](https://github.com/ipython/ipykernel/). And please google for it for next time.

Comment: i did not aim to solve the bug, as this might take to long, but i want to ask how to recreate a stable environment, i will edit the title to make that clear. As the first quest that is already linked in this quest did address the bug in spyder, it is not sufficient to answer this quest here.

Comment: further the hint 'Your post has been associated with a similar question. If this question doesn’t resolve your question, ask a new one. ' is exactly what i am doing with this quest

Comment: I cannot repopen this question. So please edit your previous one.