# Is there a way to execute smth upon window destruction tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm trying to do something when a window is manually closed in tkinter and don't know a method/function to do so. A simple example of what im trying to do in a smaller scale.

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
rootIsClosed = False # how to do this? How to make it True?
if rootIsClosed:     # ?
    new_win = Tk()
    x = Label(new_win, text='why did you close the program').pack()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/111155/how-do-i-handle-the-window-close-event-in-tkinter) answer which talks about how to handle exiting a window.

In short, you can do this:

```
from tkinter import *
root = Tk() #create new root

def on_close():
    #this is the code you provided

    new_win = Tk()
    x = Label(new_win, text='why did you close the program').pack()

root.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", on_close) # main part of the code, calls on_close
root.mainloop()
```

Note that this doesn't allow you to actually close the window, so you can do this to close the window:

```
from tkinter import *
root = Tk()

def on_close():
    new_win = Tk()
    x = Label(new_win, text='why did you close the program').pack()
    root.destroy() #only difference, root.destroy closes the original window.

root.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", on_close)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Need to call `root.destroy()` inside `on_close()`.

Comment: @acw1668 fixed that in my second code snippet