# How to detect a button click Python Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, button

I have a question, how to detect a button click?
I find everywhere a solution (not useful in my opinion)

```
button = Button(window,command=when_clicked)
```

I need to detect the closing of the wiget.

```
button = tk.Button(exit_button, text="Exit", command=new_a_program.destroy)
```

I thought to use a counter but it doesn't work because it triggers me one step in the module by clicking on the button.

Thank you for your help :

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I handle the window close event in Tkinter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/111155/how-do-i-handle-the-window-close-event-in-tkinter)

Comment: I tried on this site to find a solution but I have a problem with it, I have to write such an algorithm:
"if I press "Exit" close wigdet and the "Exit" button - I close the widget but I am left with the "Exit" button on the screen.

Comment: I did, maybe someone will find it useful :D button = tk.Button(self.exit_button, text="Exit", command=self.Close)