# check if Toplevel windows was closed?

Tags: python, tkinter, customtkinter

I have a tkinter app, created with customtkinter:

```
import customtkinter

class App(customtkinter.CTk):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        Extra()

        self.mainloop()

class Extra(customtkinter.CTkToplevel):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.geometry("400x300")

        self.label = customtkinter.CTkLabel(self, text="ToplevelWindow")
        self.label.pack(padx=20, pady=20)

App()
```

I am trying to figure out code that checks if the Extra window has been closed. I've been looking around and cannot seem to find anything useful. Is there a way of doing this?

Comment: I know that in vanilla tkinter you can use `<widget>.winfo_exists()` to check if a widget exists or not, which also works on instances of `tkinter.Toplevel`. You might give that a try!

Comment: Wouldn't that mean I have to run some kind of timer to constantly check if the window exists? That seems quite clunky :(

Comment: Potentially, but that depends on what you're actually trying to accomplish. If you just want to call a function, i.e. do something when the window is closed, this is pretty trivial to implement. And periodic timers in tkinter aren't too hard to deal with either thanks to the `after()` method

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on answers in this thread [How do I handle the window close event in Tkinter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/111155/how-do-i-handle-the-window-close-event-in-tkinter):

> If a WM_DELETE_WINDOW message arrives when you haven't defined a handler, then Tk handles the message by destroying the window for which it was received.

We could add a `protocol` named `WM_DELETE_WINDOW` and use the `self.destroy()` method as such:

```py
class Extra(customtkinter.CTkToplevel):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.geometry("400x300")
        self.label = customtkinter.CTkLabel(self, text="ToplevelWindow")
        self.label.pack(padx=20, pady=20)

        self.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", self.closed) # <-- adding the protocol

    def closed(self):
        print("I've been closed!")
        self.destroy()
```

---

[image]

---

Resulting in:

```
I've been closed!
```

And we then terminate the extra window.